# Occurrence of a letter case sensitive

Tags: python

I am trying to find occurrence of letter 'b' and 'B'. the code that I have written works perfectly. Is there a better way that i can do this.
My code:

```
def count_letter_b(string):
    #TODO: Your code goes here
    a = int(string.count('B'))
    b = int(string.count('b'))
    return a + b

print count_letter_b("Bubble Bungle")
```

Comment: this code wont work. fix identation :)

Comment: And if you fix indentation, just call `.lower()` on your input and count that.

Comment: `str.count` already returns an int. `int(str.count(...))` is redundant

Comment: thanks guys, all these have been helpful tips @PatrickArtner

Comment: @roganjosh,  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the string to uppercase (or lowercase),  then count the occurrences:

```
string.upper().count('B')
```

---

So, overall, your code will look like this:

```
def count_letter_b(string):
    return string.upper().count('B')
```

**Note**: no need to cast to `int(..)` as the result of `str.count` is already an `int`

Comment: nice solution :) specific though

Comment: @ReutSharabani, yes indeed. I am trying to build upon what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you only want to apply the same computation to a varying amount of letters you may want them to be arguments (`count_letter(s, letters)`), but anyway, here is a more functional example:

```
def count_letter_b(string):
    return sum(map(string.count, 'Bb'))
```

This uses the `str.count` version that is bound to your input string instance.

Note that you're shadowing the name `string` if you use it as a parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
# count in upper string, upper character
def countInvariantChars(c,s):
    return s.upper().count(c.upper())

# list comprehensions + length    
def countInvariantChars2(c,s):
    return len([x for x in s if c.upper() == x.upper()])

# sum ones of list comprehension
def countInvariantChars3(c,s):
    return sum([1 for x in s if c.upper() == x.upper()])

print(countInvariantChars("b","Bubble Bungle"))    
print(countInvariantChars2("b","Bubble Bungle"))    
print(countInvariantChars3("b","Bubble Bungle"))
```

Output (pyfiddle.io):

```
read-only@bash: 4
4
4
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

`def count_letter_b(string):
     return string.lower().count('b')
print(count_letter_b(string))`